# How to convert rows to column based on specific column in Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a table with four fields `id, date, name, type` I want to show data based on type here is my table data

[image]

and here is  what I want expected output

[image]

Comment: read up on PIVOT

Comment: @OldProgrammer how to do this using pivot i have tried but no luck

Comment: It looks like what you're really trying to do is join the "in" rows to the out "rows", but it's not at all clear what connects the first 4 columns to the latter 4 columns. Some more details on what you're trying to accomplish would be helpful.